# What would be the least expensive technological solution (considering all costs) to put on Lagrange Point 1 to affect global warming?

Tags: cost, climate, sunlight

For example, I did read about an [exploding asteroid](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/science/2019/09/18/blowing-up-asteroid-block-sun-could-stop-global-warming-happened/#:%7E:text=Around%20half%2Da%2Dbillion%20years,from%20run%2Daway%20global%20warming.) at Lagrange Point 1 to block some of the Sun's light. Just two degrees change in Earth's overall temperature can trigger [an Ice Ages](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/understanding-climate/climate-change-incoming-sunlight#:%7E:text=The%20Sun%27s%20energy%20output%20changes,it%20is%20at%20solar%20minimum.).

**There was a development relevant to this question:**
"Scientists led by Yoram Rozen, a physics professor and the director of the Asher Space Research Institute at Technion-Israel Institute of Technology, say they are ready to build a prototype shade to show that the idea will work.
Prototype shade of 100 square feet at the cost of $ \$10-\$20$ million." [nytimes.com](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/02/02/climate/sun-shade-climate-geoengineering.html)

Comment: "All costs" can't possibly be calculated as a number.  Eg, reducing the amount of  sunlight reaching Earth will have a negative affect on all plants relying on photosynthisis.

Comment: @GregMiller - This is not a permanent solution, it should be easy to roll back. Also, it will block just a small portion of sunlight.

Comment: I would imagine that the transparency of this object could be adjusted to block more light when the southern hemisphere is in focus - to protect Antarctica.

Comment: Downvoting for two reasons:  I think an appropriate answer to this question would require an in-depth study (though maybe one already exists that could just be quoted from, who knows), and mentioning a Lagrange point doesn't make the question about Lagrange points so the tag is inappropriate.  Tags should indicate what the question is about.

Comment: For this kind of question, it's better to ask for the lowest cost schemes *that have been proposed and reasonably thought through* (e.g. published in something like a peer-reviewed journal) rather than ask for readers to do the work themselves. And in this case "better" means more likely to be answered and less likely to be closed. The idea is that Stack Exchange answers need to be *supported by facts and sources* which would really be difficult if someone had to work this problem themselves.

Comment: If you ask it that way, I am sure there are such proposed and published schemes that can be cited. You can also (separately) ask if there is any *benefit* to putting sunblock at L1 over putting it in Earth orbit besides a factor of 2, since things at L1 will need stationkeeping or they'll wander off on their own heliocentric orbits, where as things in Earth orbit will tend to stay put for centuries provided they're not too low or too high.

Comment: @uhoh - personally, I would think of semi-translucent inflatables, but my googling did not bring any proposed projects of that kind.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance did not take long to find the relevant wikipedia page with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_sunshade#One_Fresnel_lens. Your questions would have a less drama if you took the time you spent finding pictures that are unrelated and looked up the relevant wikipedia pages and followed the source links. Both to read and to include in your question to show what you already know. Translucent shields are probably not mentioned since in general for the same mass lifted to orbit a fully mirrored structure will block more light.

Comment: @GremlinWranger - I mentioned semi-translucent inflatables because you can change the color and saturation of the gas inside. This would allow for precise calibration of blocked sunlight.

Comment: "Exploding an asteroid" mentuoned in the OP is a lot different than "semi-translucent inflatables" you mentioned in the comments.  You might want to try to focus the question better.

Comment: @GregMiller - this question is one downvote from disappearing. Opportunities for brainstorming did not work this time.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance funny, it's like we're on a Question and Answer site, not a brainstorming site

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance It's like you are against the most obvious solution to global warming, which is to stop injecting so many greenhouse gases into the atmosphere. There are many very good reasons to avoid geoengineering solutions, particularly so with regard to wackadoodle ideas that will take decades to implement, that have a low chance of working, that cost a lot of money, and that deprive humanity of a key resource in space such as the Sun-Earth L1 area.

Comment: @DavidHammen - You are mixing engineering inventions and development with decision making to deploy them. The more technical options you have available (to fight global warming) the better decisions you can make.

Comment: @DavidHammen - "to stop injecting so many greenhouse gases into the atmosphere" -  go ahead, stop human greed, stop wars, stop developing countries trying to get rich. Challenges are created to stimulate technological progress and geoengineering solutions will be part of it.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance I get where you're coming from, though I agree that forcing an emissions cut-off at-source is a way better (and logistically easier) solution than geoengineering. We live in a society that prioritizes human greed, instead of logic or science. progress in today's world is only for the sake of profit, and that's awful (especially for those of us who actually have studies, experiments or scientific progress that is then side-lined because it isn't profitable.)

Comment: In terms of your question, any sort of shade works well, but a controlled shade, like for instance, a stationary venetian blind system of sail slats that open or close to modulate radiation. Another option is, as above, to prevent the use of carbon emitting fuels. (and a note on this to help with understanding would be to realise that most of our emissions are produced by steel, aluminium and concrete production, all of which rely on vast amounts of concentrated heat, which could instead be produced renewably, but wouldn't be as cheap.)

Comment: I expect the best kind of 'sunshades in space' to reduce global warming would be orbital solar power satellites, that displace use of fossil fuels, but those are not a credible option either. Nor expected to be cost effective if they were within our capabilities.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance if you want you can add a self answer to the question based on that link, though waiting until they have published more numbers might be wise (you need 100,000 of these to get 1 square km of shade, and a least a million square km of shade for a very large $number if naively scaled up). In particular this current round of media appears to be based on PR not a paper and is I think an attempt to get funding to build a prototype.

Comment: "Least Expensive thing to send to L1 to affect global warming" -- a shipping container full of fossil fuel executives. </sarcasm>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding price tags for solar shades is tricky, there are two Wikipedia [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_mirror_(climate_engineering)) on the [topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_sunshade), with various price tags from billions to trillions depending on assumptions, starting with how much heat reduction you feel is 'correct'.

Relevant is that L1 is actually hard to get to and unstable. Any transfer from earth or elsewhere in space will need to use non trivial amounts of thrust to take station there, and some means to keep station against gravity perturbation and the solar wind.

If using reflective sails it is possible to do both by [solar sailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail) taking position slightly away from L1 and using reflected thrust to counter the gravity. This means just blowing up an asteroid passing by pointless since the debris will keep going, and even if pushed into position is problematic since the lighter (and most useful for shade) debris will tend to get blow away while the heavier will hang around endangering any future attempts. Though if you dump enough of that dust and debris into the upper atmosphere you might get a [cooling effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter).

This [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1859907/) includes a useful graph

[image: Graph of masses for various sunshields in millions of tons]

Showing mass of sunshield in millions of tonnes for various proposals to achieve 1.5% reduction in received sunlight.

This 'millions of tons' mass is the second issue, since it is not just to LEO but to out near earth escape velocity, so sensible costings are even harder. An assumed element of many shade schemes is building and launching from the moon, which can give nicely low 'cost of shade' but involves building a substantial moonbase and rail launch system first.

If launching from earth on Hydrocarbon burning rockets at this scale the 'cost' of the released carbon needs to be factored into final sunshield performance.

The linked paper uses some very ambitious assumptions including gun launch to come up with 0.2% of earth's total wealth per year spread across 50 years.

All of this makes 'cost of a sunshade' pretty broad, from 'what moonbase does with mining waste' to 'more money than exists in the global economy'.

Update based on tweaking of question in terms of lowering cost using an asteroid:
The utility of the shade depends mostly on the cross sectional area, with a dust cloud from an exploded asteroid being a mass inefficient sphere - in most cases if you can get an asteroid parked at L1, processing the mass into something approximating a flat sheet will justify the effort of getting the sheet making machine out there.

---

[Link](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0136648) to paper discussing size and position of a solar shade based on discussion in comments. Includes possibility of using slightly sub optimal orbital placement to tweak cooling distribution for possibly more effective total result (or make it into a weapon).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145311/discussion-on-answer-by-gremlinwranger-what-would-be-the-least-expensive-technol); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.